# Show that for $f(x)<c$ and some $a>0$, $\mathbb P(X>a) \geqslant 1-ac$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The more complete version of the question is as follows:

> Let $X$ be a positive random variable with probability density function $f$. For
>   some $c > 0$, suppose $f(x) \leqslant c$ for all $x$. Show that for all $a > 0$, $$\mathbb P(X > a) \geqslant 1 − ac.$$

I know that we want to use the properties of continuous distribution functions, but I just can't seem to make the jump from the properties to the final step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X > a) &= 1 - \mathbb P(X\leqslant a)\\
&= 1 - \int_0^a f(x)\ \mathsf dx\\
&\geqslant 1 - \int_0^a c\ \mathsf dx\\
&= 1 - ac.
\end{align}